# Columns with frequency and avg number

Tags: r

From a data frame like this

```
data.frame(id= c(1,1,2,3,3), visits = c(32,30,1,2,4))
```

How is it possible to produce a average number column of visits per numi but also add a new column which will have the number/frequency of numbers exist in numi column
Expected output:

```
data.frame(id=  c(1,2,3), numi_frq = c(2,1,2), average = c(31,1,3))
```

Comment: Try `aggregate(. ~ id, d1, FUN = function(i) c(numi_fq = length(i), average = mean(i)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
Data <- data.frame(id= c(1,1,2,3,3), visits = c(32,30,1,2,4))
Data %>% group_by(id)%>% summarise(N=n(),Avg=mean(visits))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id     N   Avg
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     2    31
2     2     1     1
3     3     2     3
```